# Send HTML to server-side PHP through AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send HTML that is in a form to a server-side script so I can save it in the database. What I'm sending is a query string, and every time the HTML contains a character like a comma or ampersand, the rest of the HTML gets truncated at that point.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

When sending a request you should properly URL encode parameteres:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo.php',
    data: { html: '<html>You can use whatever characters you want here</html>' },
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result) {

    }
});
```

or:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo.php',
    data: { html: $('#someTextFieldWhichMightContainHtml').val() },
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result) {

    }
});
```

Now you can safely read the `html` variable in your PHP script: `$.GET["html"]`.

I suppose that right now your code looks something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo.php?html=' + $('#someTextField').val(),
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result) {

    }
});
```

I would recommend you to never use string concatenations and always use the `data` hash.

Comment: is data html is preserved keyword , if you mention as html will it take care of these type issues...

Comment: @gov, no `html` is not a reserved word. You could use any name you like. The important part is to use the `data` hash.

Comment: i always pass as query string thats why i am asking, where did we use hash in the above code, i am just asking for learning purposes, don't mind

Comment: @gov, the `data` parameter of the `$.ajax` method is a hash (key/value pairs).

Comment: @DarinDimitrov what if i don't want to use php i want to use asp.net the how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As Darin Dimitrov said, it needs to be urlencoded. I use these function to encode and decode in javascript.

```
function urlencode(str) {
    return escape(str).replace(/\+/g,'%2B').replace(/%20/g, '+').replace(/\*/g, '%2A').replace(/\//g, '%2F').replace(/@/g, '%40');
}

function urldecode(str) {
    return unescape(str.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

Originally from a post on phpbuilder I believe.

Comment: Wow. Ugly wheel reinvention. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Why on earth would you use such functions when there's [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent). Rolling your own encoding functions is rarely a good thing.

Comment: Woah, clearly I need to update my code. Thanks for the notice.